# Correct way to restrict list of classes to those which extend a particular abstract class in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have an abstract class that basically extends an existing abstract class:

```
export abstract class NamedFoo extends Foo {
  name: string
}
```

and a few other classes that implement this abstract class:

```
class LargeFoo extends NamedFoo {
  ...
}

class OtherFoo extends NamedFoo {
  ...
}
```

and I'd like to have a list of these classes, but can't seem to get the right typing for it. These all fail:

```
const myNamedFooClasses: (typeof NamedFoo)[] = [LargeFoo, OtherFoo];
const myNamedFooClasses: <T extends NamedFoo>[] = [LargeFoo, OtherFoo];
```

The following works(?) but is incredibly ugly, to the point that I think I'm doing something wrong:

```
const myNamedFooClasses: { new(parameterOne: ParameterOneType, parameterTwo: string, ...): NamedFoo }[] = [LargeFoo, OtherFoo];
```

This could maybe be mitigated by breaking the ugliness out and declaring it a `type` of its own, but that doesn't really solve my underlying question. Maybe an extended abstract class for NamedFoo is the wrong tool for the job?

Basically, is there a "more right" or at least less wrong way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the constructor signature as an interface:

```js
interface FooConstructor {
    new (...args: any[]): NamedFoo;
}

const foos: FooConstructor[] = [LargeFoo, OtherFoo];
```

You can also inline `FooConstructor`, as you did in your example, but I prefer this more explicit syntax. Pay attention that with this syntax you do not have any restriction upon the signature of the constructor. If you can, you should put the constructor signature in the `FooConstructor` definition, so you can call the items in the array to build instances.